# Searching github commits with certain word

Tags: github, github-api

From Github API i'm trying to get commit messages containing a certain word. But when i search it returns with that specific word not the full sentence (if available) . For example when i search for ['hello'](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hello&type=Commits) i'm expecting everything including '[hello world](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hello%20world&type=Commits)' or 'hello dude'

Answer (score 3):

Actually your search includes `hello` from sentences but it is only displaying the most relevant search results. Unfortunately, GitHub search provides a maximum of 1000 results. And the 1000 most relevant search results for `hello` does not include `hellow world`.

What you could do is include another filter say `commit date` so that the number of serach results in less than 1000. Ofcourse, now you have to deal with the unfortunately low API limit for GitHub search API.

For example, you could could use the GitHub search API and make the following request to search for all commits that includes the word `good` and that were committed on the 14th of October. In the result you find matches for `looking good` etc.

`curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview' \https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=good+committer-date:2017-10-14`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't have this problem with less common words. Wish they have a 'most recent' filter.

Comment: Hey.. you can sort by `most recently committed`.

Comment: Tried that, its not helping.